# Converting selected polygons to lines using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

In PyQGIS 3, how can I convert selected polygons with n sides, into another layer with n lines?

```py
import processing

mapcanvas = iface.mapCanvas()
layer = mapcanvas.currentLayer()
features = layer.getFeatures()

line_path = "C:/Users/Me/Desktop/pyqgis/line.shp"

#### I need something like this processing method, but instead of a polygon in the input, i need the selected feature. 
#processing.run("qgis:polygonstolines", {'INPUT': polygon_path,'OUTPUT': line_path}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you can extract selected polygons to memory, secondly convert them to lines, then explode the lines.

This script works in QGIS 3.8, but it doesn't in QGIS 3.4.13:

```
import processing

layer = iface.activeLayer()
selected = processing.run("native:saveselectedfeatures", {'INPUT':layer, 'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})["OUTPUT"]    
temp_lines = processing.run("native:polygonstolines", {'INPUT': selected, 'OUTPUT':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})["OUTPUT"]

line_path = "C:/Users/Me/Desktop/pyqgis/line.shp"
processing.runAndLoadResults("native:explodelines", {'INPUT': temp_lines, 'OUTPUT': line_path})
```

---

This script works in both QGIS 3.4.13 and 3.8:

```
import processing

layer = iface.activeLayer()
selected = processing.run("qgis:saveselectedfeatures", {'INPUT':layer, 'OUTPUT':'memory:'})["OUTPUT"]    
temp_lines = processing.run("qgis:polygonstolines", {'INPUT':selected,'OUTPUT':'memory:'})["OUTPUT"]

line_path = "C:/Users/Me/Desktop/pyqgis/line.shp"   
result = processing.run("qgis:explodelines", {'INPUT':temp_lines,'OUTPUT':'memory:'})["OUTPUT"]
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(result)
```

Comment: Thanks, but i had this error message in console:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.4\apps\Python37\lib\code.py" ....
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 105, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 127, in runAlgorithm
    raise QgsProcessingException(msg)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Error: Algorithm native:polygonstolines not found`

Comment: What is the version of QGIS you use? I don't encounter that error.

Comment: 3.4.14 - Madeira

Comment: I didn't found the answer, please, can you help me?

Comment: I don't get any error when I use the script. Therefore I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: Do you always get that error?

Comment: Yes, does it has something to do with QGIS version?

Comment: I use QGIS 3.8 and 3.4.13. I've editted the answer. The second script works in 3.4.13. Try that one. I guess it works.

Comment: Amazing!!! It worked :)